# Entity Framework Code First Find vs SingleOrDefault (Eager Loading)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using Entity Framework 4.2 (Code First) to access my database. I was under the assumption that if I queried an entity using `SingleOrDefault` it would only query the database if the entity was not already being tracked, but this does not appear to be the case. The `Find` method on the other hand, does appear to be doing this. The problem with `Find` is that it doesn't appear to allow me to load related data.

Is there a way to use the `Find` method but also eagerly load data ? As an example, I want to load a book and all of its reviews:

```
// Load book from the database
Book book = context.Books.Find(1); 
context.Entry<Book>(book).Collection<Review>.Load(); // Book.Reviews is now populated

// Load book from the change tracker
// This will include all Reviews as well
Book book2 = context.Books.Find(1);
```

With `SingleOrDefault` I can load the Reviews when I get the book using Include:

```
// Load book + reviews from the database
Book book = Book.Include("Reviews").SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == 1);

// Doing the same thing again requeries the database
Book book2 = Book.Include("Reviews").SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == 1);
```

Is there a way to get the behavior of `Find` with the eager loading of `SingleOrDefault` ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `Find` method is for searching single entity by key. The `SingleOrDefault` method is for executing query. Eager loading can be only part of the query which is really executed on the database so it cannot be used with `Find`.

As a workaround you can rewrite it this way:

```
// This will check only on in-memory collection of loaded entities
Book book = context.Books.Local.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == 1);
if (book == null)
{
    book = context.Books.Include(b => b.Review).SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == 1);
}
```

Comment: Had no idea this Local property existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If lazy-loading is enable Find will work for you. Try this:

```
Book book = context.Books.Find(1);
int n = book.Reviews.Count;
```

Check the value for the "n" variable. EF must load the collection when you access it first time.

Comment: His point is that he doesn't want to use lazy-loading and wants them eager loaded.